# How to make sure Mongoose keeps the order of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array:
`["wordswordswords", "somewords", "otherwords"]` and I'm trying to update it to a `mongoose` document using:

```js
Collection.findOne({ criteria: value }, (err, res) => {
  res.value = array;
  res.save();
});
```

It saves the array just fine, however, the array is being sorted in alphabetical order. That way, from this:

`["wordswordswords", "somewords", "otherwords"]`

I get:

`["otherwords", "somewords", "wordswordswords"]`

in the database.

The array order is important to me in this case.

Comment: If mongo doesn't guarantee array order, you could save it as a map from index to value and reconstruct the array when you load the data, i.e. `res.value = array.reduce((o, x, i) => { o[i] = x; return o }, {})`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the lightning-fast response. It's an interesting way of solving the issue, I will try to implement that into my code, although it will take a lot of time, as I already prepared it to be an array in a lot of places. Anyway, a simple loop over the keys + getting the value for that key will do.

Comment: Are you sure the sort is happening on the save? It may only be sorting on the retrieval (which you can control).

Comment: Also, could you drop me a quick & tidy way to reconstruct the array?

Comment: @terrymorse yes, it happens on save. Even before retrieving the data, it's shuffled around in the Compass app.

Comment: Hmm, could you serialize the array with JSON.stringify? It would then be just a string, which you could JSON.parse on retrieval.

Comment: @nortex_dev I don't get this behaviour, where do you see that the array values are sorted? Do you have any screenshot?

Comment: @nortex_dev try https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinEvilWorker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by @wbadart.

The key was to map the array to an object:

`foo.value = bar.reduce((o, x, i) => { o[i] = x; return o }, {})`

so from an array like: `["wordswordswords", "somewords", "otherwords"]` I get `{'0': "wordswordswords", '1': "somewords", '2': "otherwords"}`.

Then, it's simple to reconstruct the ordered object to an array.